# Calculate function using only bar data since condition x

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to have a function start calculating after a condition , using only bar data since condition ?
Let’s say  | `sma1= sma(close,20)` | I want to calculate sma1 using only the bars that have past since strategy entry . So in this case `sma1` would not even plot until we are 20 bars from the strategy entry bar. then plot would disappear after strategy has exited position and start recalculating again after next strategy.entry. Id like to use this to plot and to trigger position changes.

This isnt working , I sorta understand why but wondering if there is a way around it . Its Just entry and exit conditions to test the idea until lower down

```
open_long  = strategy.position_size > 0
open_short = strategy.position_size < 0

//Entry MA's
fast_ma = sma(close,10)
slow_ma = sma(close,20)

ma_long = crossover(fast_ma ,slow_ma)
ma_short =  crossover(slow_ma ,fast_ma)

//EntryRSI
rsi = rsi(close,14)

rsi_long  = rsi[1] > 50
rsi_short = rsi[1] < 50

//Exit RSI
exit_long  = crossunder(rsi,50)
exit_short = crossover(rsi,50)

//strategy
if ma_long and rsi_long
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if ma_short and rsi_short
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

if open_long and exit_long
    strategy.close("Long")
if open_short and exit_short
    strategy.close("Short")



//This is where my issue is 

x = input(10,"Variable Length")
y = 0

// if not in a position and bars since position is equal to length of MA
if strategy.position_size != 0 and barssince(strategy.position_size == 0) == x
    y := x

var_ma = sma(close,y)

plot(var_ma)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this my friend? We can set the plot conditionally and use plot.style_linebr to stop drawing if the series is na. I also changed the barssince to be >= the length.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

open_long  = strategy.position_size > 0
open_short = strategy.position_size < 0

//Entry MA's
fast_ma = sma(close,10)
slow_ma = sma(close,20)

ma_long = crossover(fast_ma ,slow_ma)
ma_short =  crossover(slow_ma ,fast_ma)

//EntryRSI
rsi = rsi(close,14)

rsi_long  = rsi[1] > 50
rsi_short = rsi[1] < 50

//Exit RSI
exit_long  = crossunder(rsi,50)
exit_short = crossover(rsi,50)

//strategy
if ma_long and rsi_long
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if ma_short and rsi_short
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

if open_long and exit_long
    strategy.close("Long")
if open_short and exit_short
    strategy.close("Short")



//This is where my issue is 

x = input(10,"Variable Length")

// if not in a position and bars since position is equal to length of MA
cond = strategy.position_size != 0 and barssince(strategy.position_size == 0) >= x

var_ma = sma(close,x)

plot(cond ? var_ma : na, style=plot.style_linebr)
```